# Android: cannot find arm images for api 11,12,13

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to download the system images for the android emulator for the apis 11,12,13 but on sdk manager there is no option to download them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This keeps popping up :)
Up to API level 14 (4.0) system images were not a separate item but part of "SDK Platform". Install "SDK Platform" for api levels you need and you will get system images.